# How to check/tick a CheckBox in the item renderer?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer

I have a grid table that contains ship objects(data provider accepts a array collection of ships objects) and displays just the name of ship and date in the grid table. My ship object has a property called checkList a boolean value, To be used as data binding in my checkbox item renderer.(To make the check box ,tick and untick)

I want to check my checkbox when I add a Image object in to a container. The Image object that is being added to the container has a id. I want to match that Image id to my shipId in the data grid table and check the check box for that particular record.

So my Image object listens to the add event and so when the Image object is added to a container. It calls the addHandler() function where it gets the id of the image and the loops though the data grid table to find the matching id and check the CheckBox. My looping works nicely.Using Alert.show() I can see that it matches the id and sets the boolean value to, true for the check box to be ticked. However the check box is not ticked.

These are my codes. Even though the checkList property for that particular record is set to true. The check box is not ticked. I dont Know whats the problem is. I am a student and new to flex.Can some one pls help me ?

My MXML view: My Grid Table

```
<s:DataGrid id="arrivalTable" x="-1" y="-1" width="302" height="205" requestedRowCount="4" 
                dataProvider="{myArrivalShips}" >               
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>                   
                <s:GridColumn dataField="shipName" headerText="Arrival Ships" itemRenderer="DesignItemRenderer.myCustomToolTipRenderer" width="130" ></s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="ETA" headerText="ETD" itemRenderer="DesignItemRenderer.myCheckBoxRenderer"></s:GridColumn>                                                         
            </s:ArrayList>                  
        </s:columns>                
    </s:DataGrid>
```

My Image object listens add event.

```
displayImg.addEventListener(FlexEvent.ADD,addHandler);
```

This is my addHandler() event Function:

```
protected function addHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    var ImageShipId:String = Image(event.currentTarget).id;             
    var destination:BorderContainer = Image(event.currentTarget).owner as BorderContainer;
    var destinationId:String = destination.id;          

    if( destinationId == "bct_HoldingArea" ){

        for(var j:int = 0; j<arrivalTable.dataProvider.length; j++){

            var myShip:Ship = arrivalTable.dataProvider.getItemAt(j) as Ship;
            var myShipId:String = myShip.shipID.toString();

            if(StringUtil.trim(myShipId) == StringUtil.trim(ImageShipId)){                          
                myShip.checkList = true;
                Alert.show("The ship name : " + myShip.shipName +"\n" + "The Ship selected : " + myShip.checkList);
            }
        }           
    }               
}
```

My check Box Item renderer :

```
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">    
<s:HGroup>
    <s:Label text="{data.ETD}"  paddingTop="8"/>        
    <s:CheckBox id="myCheckBox" enabled="false" selected="{data.checkList}"  />
</s:HGroup>
```

Comment: what about arrivalTable.validateNow(); after setting checkList to true?

Comment: The answer to this question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078627/flex-4-itemrenderer-for-list#comment21209461_15078627

Comment: @M.S.Nayak no sir didt work.:(

Comment: @www.Flextras.com hi sir I saw the question and answer u recommended. looks like he using the selection property of the list to get the selected item in the list?I dont know if i understand correctly pls pardon me if i am wrong. For my situation I am not selecting any rows.so PropertyChangeEvent i cant say if its selected or not selected? And must I add a override method for my checkbox too ? If I must, what is the override method? Pls can u give me an example or guide me how i can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use "refresh" method of the dataprovider after updating an object:

```
(arrivalTable.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).refresh();
```

So your function will look like this:

```
protected function addHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
var ImageShipId:String = Image(event.currentTarget).id;             
var destination:BorderContainer = Image(event.currentTarget).owner as BorderContainer;
var destinationId:String = destination.id;          

if( destinationId == "bct_HoldingArea" ){

    for(var j:int = 0; j<arrivalTable.dataProvider.length; j++){

        var myShip:Ship = arrivalTable.dataProvider.getItemAt(j) as Ship;
        var myShipId:String = myShip.shipID.toString();

        if(StringUtil.trim(myShipId) == StringUtil.trim(ImageShipId)){                          
            myShip.checkList = true;

            (arrivalTable.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).refresh();

            Alert.show("The ship name : " + myShip.shipName +"\n" + "The Ship selected : " + myShip.checkList);
        }
    }           
}               
}
```

**//EDIT**
The issue with the row in the middle seems to be a so called "middle row bug". I have found some info [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-28138).

To avoid this strange thing try to change your Renderer code in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">   
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

        [Bindable]override public function get data():Object
        {
            return ObjectUtil.copy(super.data);;
        }

        override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            super.data = value;
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:HGroup>
    <s:Label text="{data.ETD}"  paddingTop="8"/>
    <s:CheckBox id="myCheckBox" enabled="false" selected="{data.checkList}"/>
</s:HGroup> 
</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

**//EDIT**

A short explanation of this trick: I have found that data update occurs for every row except the middle one.  I have tried to follow the source code of the data grid. I think the code line responsible for this action is:

```
renderer.data = dataItem;
```

in the GridLayout.as class.

This line causes data update for each row except the middle one. Why? Flex compares both sides of this expression and does nothing if they are equal. In our case they are not equal but it seems to be a real bug. Whatever... We need to wait till Flex team correct the issue.

As a temporary workaround I have changed the left side of the expression brutally by clonning the Object in the "get" function. So the comparison should now return FALSE in any case and the data property should be updated for each row.

The set function could be deleted, but it is a good place for debugging of same issues.

It is not a good approach but it is better than nothing.

Comment: Hi!! you are awesome ! It works!! :) But I found there is this small weird problem... When the number of records in the dataGrid table is odd number. There is always one check box that is not ticked/checked. So for example when there is 3 records 1,2,3 the 2nd one do not get ticked. When there is 5 records 1,2,3,4,5 the 3th one do not get checked. But If the number of records in that data grid is even it works fine. I didt make any other change to my codes. I just added the line u suggested.. how can i solve this problem? Thanks so much :)

Comment: Let me know if I need to rephrase my explanation if this is not clear. Thanks:)

Comment: Yes, you are right! It is so strange for me. The object's property of the data provider is changed but the ItemRenderer for the middle record does not see it. If you use just the field's value without the Renderer you see a correct value. Let me try to find a workaround.

Comment: I have edited my post. Now it works good for me but the error has been  realy strange.

Comment: Its works wonderfully!!! :) :) Thank you soo much!!! I really appreciate it!! you saved me! May I know how the override methods works to solve this problem ? what is it actually doing ?

Comment: I have edited my post again. Have a look at the explanation. I think it is correct.

Comment: really appreciated it. I thought I should not blindly copy the solution at least try to understand on my part. :)